Aiogram Dispatcher() takes no arguments
Пишу бота с aiogram, но PyCharm ругает Dispatcher и executor со словами, что они пустые:
import openai
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor

token = 'токен тг бота'

openai.api_key = 'аи ключ'

bot = Bot(token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
async def send(message : types.Message):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model='text-davinci-004',
        promt=message.text,
        temperature=0.9,
        max_tokens=1000,
        top_p=1.0,
        freauency_penalty=0.0,
        presence_penalty=0.6,
        stop=["You"]
    )

    await message.answer(response['choices'][0]['text'])

    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)

Ошибка
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "c:\Users\Грачики\VC\32", line 11, in <module>     
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: Dispatcher() takes no arguments


Пожалуйста, предоставьте текст ошибки. Если есть возможность предоставить лог ошибки - будет здорово

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\Грачики\VC\32", line 11, in <module>     dp = Dispatcher(bot)          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: Dispatcher() takes no arguments

Какая у вас версия aiogram

я переустановил с 3 на 2.5, ошибка пропала, код запускается, но бот так и не работает
